# Exit button on login form

Tags: vb.net

Is this sufficient code for an exit button on my form?

This is my code:

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
Dim response As MsgBoxResult
        response = MsgBox("Do you want to close form?", MsgBoxStyle.Question + MsgBoxStyle.YesNo, "Confirm")
        If response = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
            Me.Dispose()
        ElseIf response = MsgBoxResult.No Then 'Button to exit the program completely 
            Exit Sub
        End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Why not Me.Close instead of Me.Dispose()?

Comment: If you had a database connection open, you should close it. If you had COM objects you should take care of them.

Comment: You should also use MessageBox.Show() instead of the legacy MsgBox().  I've seen weird things happen with forms and the message when using MsgBox().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is sufficient but:

1. You should use `Me.Close()` instead of `Me.Dispose()`.
2. If this is the exit from your application completely and you have any unmanaged resources (e.g. database connections, files open, COM objects, etc). you should close them/clean them up.